# Entity ranking in Google Knowledge graph for Freebase entities

Tags: ranking, freebase, google-knowledge-graph

Each entity in freebase had a popularity score which was available through search API . This score was and is not available in the dump.

This score is apparently available through the Knowledge graph API. However there seems to be a major bug in the same. When I the freebase MID for search(using "ids" parameter) for the entity I get one score and when I use the text search (using "query" parameter ) I get starkly different value for the resultScore value as below

Example: searching for "Notre Dame de Paris" using [text query](https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=Notre%20Dame%20de%20Paris&key=YourOWNKEY) and using  [FB MID](https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?ids=/m/0gtxh&key=YourOWNKEY) "/m/0gtxh" gives result score values as 2107.588623 and 21.945427 respectively.  The number varies by a factor of 100 which is pretty lame

Is this a bug? Which one is the value to be relied upon. Obviously cannot use a mix of score from two methods as results would be pretty useless

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Knowledge Graph reference](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/) resultScore is not a popularity score, its "An indicator of how well the entity matched the request constraints".

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. However it doesn't clarify why 2 different values are shown when a given entity is accessed using 2 different identifiers as above...

Comment: There is any answer for this questions please !!